# Remove from 3 element lift & right element from cell csv file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to remove from column:

```
X00401011013    
X05401183013
X05401183013
```

```
code:reader = csv.reader(open(myfile))
remove_me = {'X00','013'}
print('Before:')
print(open(myfile).read())***emphasized text***
for row in reader:
    new_row = []
    for column in row:
        if column not in remove_me:
            new_row.append(column)
    csv.writer(open(newfile,'a')).writerow(new_row)
print('\n\n')
print('After:')
print(open(newfile).read())
```

Output:

```
401011
540118
```

Comment: X00401011013
output:401011

Comment: what you exactly want? read complete CSV file and remove first and last 3 char's??

Comment: I want read particular complete column. and remove first and last char or digit.

Comment: what is the problem with your code then? please specify

Comment: @Ankush:- my code remove hole record remove_me = {'X00','013'} but i want remove only first & last 3 char or digit from  
X00401011013 & required o/p  401011.

Comment: I am new to python and just need a small help.
which looks like this

Comment: I am new to python and just need a small help.
which looks like this:cn_no   dmg_no     tn    clm            cnt    
20000 53879577 1 X00401011013 4
20000 53879577 1 X05401183013 5
20000 53879577 1 X05400641013 16
20000 54954713 1 X00401011013 4
20000 54954713 1 X05400640013 18
20000 54954713 1 X05401183013 5
The new file should then look like this:401011
540118
540064
plz help

Comment: To be more specific: you want to edit your values if and only if when it starts with "X00" and ends with "013". Is it so?

Answer (score 0):

inside your inner for loop, do this:

```
for column in row:
    if column.startswith('X00') and column.endswith('013'):
    column = column[3:-3]
    new_row.append(column)
```

If you want to remove left and right 3 elements for each value, you are free to remove the IF condition. I added "IF block" on the basis of latest comment that you added.